# select ith row and nth column and assign to variable in while loop

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file list.txt with two columns and n rows e.g

```
a1.txt bd.txt
b2.txt g6.txt
.....
```

I need to run a command multiple times (once for each row in list.txt), where each time the input files are `$1` and `$2` of that row.

My attempt to do this is below, where I wanted to specify the row as a variable and increment after each loop.

```
a=1
while $a<=200
do
  FILE1=$(awk 'FNR==a{$1}' ./list.txt)
  FILE2=$(awk 'FNR==a{$2}' ./list.txt)
  ./command $FILE1 $FILE2
  a=$a+1
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than that:

```
while read arg1 arg2 rest; do
  ./command $arg1 $arg2
done < list.txt
```

There is no need for awk, much less two awks for every line.